# Calling drawArrays several times keeping render buffer

Tags: javascript, glsl, webgl

I'm trying to make animation like winning solitaire card using WebGL. I wrote the following code to draw multiple cards.

```
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = canvas.height = 400;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

const gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');
const program = gl.createProgram();
const shaderSources = {
    VERTEX_SHADER: `
    precision highp float;
    attribute vec2 aCoord;
    uniform float uOffset;
    void main(void) {
        gl_Position = vec4(aCoord + vec2(uOffset, 0.0), 0.0, 1.0);
    }
    `,
    FRAGMENT_SHADER: `
    precision highp float;
    void main(void) {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    }
    `
}
for (let i in shaderSources) {
    const shader = gl.createShader(gl[i]);
    gl.shaderSource(shader, shaderSources[i]);
    gl.compileShader(shader);
    gl.attachShader(program, shader);
}
gl.linkProgram(program);
gl.useProgram(program);

const aCoordLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'aCoord');
const aCoordBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, aCoordBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
    -0.75, -0.25, -0.25, -0.25, -0.25, 0.25,
    -0.75, -0.25, -0.75, 0.25, -0.25, 0.25
]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(aCoordLocation);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, aCoordBuffer);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(aCoordLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
```

After that, when I run the following code, two red squares are drawn as expected.

```
gl.uniform1f(gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'uOffset'), 0);
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

gl.uniform1f(gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'uOffset'), 1);
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
```

However if one drawing is delayed due to animation, only one square is rendered (the first square disappears).

```
gl.uniform1f(gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'uOffset'), 0);
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

setTimeout(() => {
    gl.uniform1f(gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'uOffset'), 1);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
});
```

Is there a way to leave the render buffer when drawArray is executed multiple times with time difference ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `preserveDrawingBuffer:true` in the `WebGLContextAttributes dictionary`, passed as the second parameter to `getContext`.

See https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/#WEBGLCONTEXTATTRIBUTES